# Trying to recover data from an APFS SSD in a 2013 MacBook Air, can’t get volume to mount in macOS

Tags: data-recovery

i would appreciate any help here. I am trying to recover data off of a MacBook Air SSD. It was at the point where it would make any computer I put it into not even give me a chime or Apple logo. So, I put it in an external OWC housing and plugged it into my Linux machine. I ran testdisk and got the sector start and end numbers for the partition that I needed, and used Parted to rescue the partition. It shows up in testdisk and parted as Macintosh HD, but won’t mount. Now, i have it plugged into my MacBook Pro and it’s making a DDRESCUE image on a separate drive. When I plug the SSD a into the MacBook, it shows up in disk utility as an APFS volume that’s 500gb, but doesn’t mount. My guess is the ddrescue image won’t either. Can someone tell me how to repair this to make the disk mount to be able to recover data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start by adding the output from `diskutil list` to your question.

Comment: Did you get this fixed / answered or update to Catalina 10.15.4 recently ?